# Custom Background image is not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress theme. For adding the custom background option to my theme I have added the code in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

here I didn't put any function for default settings for background. And also my header.php is look like this

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(''); ?>>
```

as wordpress documentation suggested([Watch here in the wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds)).

After completing these steps, from wordpress Dashboard -> Appearance -> Backgorund settings it's only working for color's not working for images. Then I inspected form google chrome and in the css properties of body tag I found this

```
background-image: url('[site_url]/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Tulips.jpg')
```

So I have understood that there is something problem with the  image url.

Any one can help? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SMOF 1.5.2?
I noticed the same issues with the SMOF. Apparently when you exclude the SMOF Options_Machine on the custom-background page everything seems to be ok, until Theme Options are saved. Then the background is once again lost and [site-url] appears.

Comment: yeah  the same problem.